# How do I find Schwartz criterion (or Bayesian Information Criterion) for these three models?

Tags: self-study, markov-process, hidden-markov-model, bic

I have to find the schwarz criterion for each of the models in this maths question using RStudio but I don't know where to start. I know I need to find the free parameters but don't know how to find them or the maximised log likelihoods.Thank you!

Question:

Sequence are independent.

Three models are to be considered.

M1. No constraints on p_A, p_C, p_G and p_T other than p_A + p_C + p_G + p_T = 1.

M2. Matched C and G, ie p_C = p_G = p (say), p_A and p_T unconstrained, except by 2p + p_A + p_T = 1.

M3. Matched C and G and matched A and T, ie p_C = p_G = p and p_A = p_T = q (say), with 2p+ 2q = 1. Estimate p and q and give the Schwarz criterion for each of the three models.

Comment: Hi sophieoxfam, can you provide a bit more context for this question? It seems a bit out of place as it is worded right now.
I could guess that this refers to DNA sequences (based on the A,C,G,T letters used), but it would help if you would write out the whole exercise or explain where you encountered it.

Comment: Hi, yes it is referring to DNA sequences, am trying to find if some of the probabilities are equally assuming that the sites in the sequence are independent. I will compare the SC for each model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model M1 : you have four parameters ($p_A$, $p_C$, $p_G$, and $p_T$). However, you only have 3 **free** parameters. Indeed, once you have specified the values for three of these parameters, the value of the last one is not free for you to choose, but is constrained by the equality $p_A + p_C + p_G + p_T = 1$. For instance, if you fixed $p_A$, $p_C$, and $p_G$, then $p_T = 1 - (p_A + p_C + p_G)$. So for this model you have three free parameters.

Similarly, I'll let you find out the number of free parameters on the other two models.

As for the maximal log-likelihood, to each model corresponds a likelihood function $\mathcal{L}$, which is the probability of having your data $\mathcal{D}$ given some parameters $\theta$:

$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta) = p(\mathcal{D}|\theta)
$$

To use the BIC, you have to compute the Maximum Likelihood Estimator $\hat{\theta}$, which is the argmax of $\mathcal{L}(\theta)$. To do so, use your favorite numerical optimzation technique, depending on your models: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)